# IIS URL Rewrite Domain change 301 redirect individually only some pages and all other pages to another URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, redirect

I am new to IIS URL Rewrite rule  Regex and looking for help here.

This is a sitecore web site which is built in ASP.NET MVC. I have a one domain i.e. www.xyz.com get merged with the another domain i.e. www.abc.com . I have the 1 to 1 mapping of both www.xyz.com/test  -> www.abc.com/test1 . ALl the internal pages of www.xyz.com/xx will be mapped with the www.abc.com/foo except Homepage of www.xyz.com

- I am currently stuck at how can i,
  1) Redirect www.xyz.com/ homepage to a third party URL?
  2) At the same time keep the 1-1 mapping of www.xyz.com/internal pages with www.abc.com/internal pages

I am using IIS URL Rewrite rule to do a domain redirect of www.xyz.com to www.abc.com and looking for additional help with the homepage redirect with a third party page

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

you just need two different redirect rules,  the first rule will check for the root domain and redirect to third party url and the second rule will check for internal pages and redirect to internal pages on the new domain

it will look something like this

```
    <rule name="redirect root to third party" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^$" ignoreCase="true" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(www.)?xyz\.com$" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="<third party url here>" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="redirect to new domain" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="/(.*)" />
         <conditions>
               <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?xyz\.com$" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="http://<new domain>/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

P.S:  in the second rule, please check for /  --  i have not tested the rule myself there could be an extra slash introduced in the destination url or a slash removed,   whatever it is you will be able to fix it.  The main point here is you need two separate rules one for checking the exact domain with nothing after it and redirecting to third party and another rule for sub page redirects